# Are there infinite positive $n \in \Bbb N$ such that ($D^+_n$, |) is isomorphic to ($D^+_{4100}$, |)?

Tags: divisibility, exceptional-isomorphisms

Are there infinite positive $n \in \Bbb N$ such that ($D^+_n$, |) is isomorphic to ($D^+_{4100}$, |)?

I'm guessing no because I can't relate every element of ($D^+_{4100}$, |) to ($D^+_n$, |) because ($D^+_{4100}$, |) has finite elements. I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $4100=2^2\cdot  5^2\cdot 41$. Let $n=p^2 q^2 r$, where $p$, $q$, and $r$ are distinct primes.

Comment: Yes, that means that 4100 has 18 divisors. I know that every positive integer can be represented as the product of prime numbers but I still don't know how to prove they are (not) isomorphic.

Comment: The **count** of the number of divisors is not enough to prove isomorphism. Note that for example $3^{17}$ also has $18$ (positive) divisors. But for the $n$ of the hint, we get an isomorphism by mapping any divisor $2^a5^b 41^c$ of $4100$ to the divisor $p^aq^b r^c$ of $n$. This mapping preserves the divisibility relation.

Comment: For any two numbers $m$ and $n$, we get isomorphism if the prime power decompositions of $m$ and $n$ have the same **structure**. The actual primes used do not matter.

Comment: What do you mean by structure of the prime power decompositions?

Comment: Let $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ and $n=q_1^{a_1}\cdots q_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the  $q_i$ are distinct primes. Then the prime power decompositions have the same structure. (The number of primes is the same, and the sequence of exponents is the same.) So for example $2^2\cdot 3^7$ has the same structure as $11^2\cdot 2^7$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If the prime power decompositions of $m$ and $n$ have the same structure, then  $(D^+_n,$ |$)$ is isomorphic to $(D^+_m,$ |$)$, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The converse also holds.

Comment: So that means that it is false that every $n$ can be written as $2^a5^b41^c$ and ($D^+_n$, |) is not isomorphic to ($D^+_{4100}$, |)for all $n$?

Comment: Well, trivially if $a=2$, $b=2$, $c=1$ we have isomorphism. Less trivially, we have isomorphism for $2^241^25^1$, and $5^241^22^1$. That's all, the obvious one and two others. But we can use **any** $n=p^2q^2r^1$ where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes, which gives us infinitely many.

Comment: But if, for example, I take $n=8$, I can't write $8$ as $p^2q^2r^1$... What am I missing?

Comment: In that case we do not have isomorphism with the set of divisors of $4100$, the numbers of divisors are not even the same. I am saying that **if** $n$ can be written as $p^2q^2r^1$, **then** the set of divisors of $n$ is order isomorphic to the set of divisors of $4100$. And there are infinitely many numbers of the form $p^2q^2r^1$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes, since there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Oh, I see it! So there are some numbers that don't satisfy the condition, but we know that there are infinitely many primes so there are infinitely many numbers of the form $p^2q^2r^1$. However, do I need to prove this?

Comment: You do not need to prove there are infinitely many primes, it can be considered a standard fact. A proof is quite easy, you probably know one.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the proof. What I'm asking is if I need to prove that the fact that there are infinitely many primes implies that there are infinitely many numbers of the form $p^2q^2r^1$.

Comment: No! Let $p$ and $q$ be fixed, like $2$ and $3$. Let $r$ roam freely over the rest of the primes. Hard to know whether it is too trivial to mention. I think yes, but it's your decision.

Comment: Seems like a hard proof!

Comment: Surely what I wrote in the comment above is not hard.

Comment: Finally, I have to prove that  $(D^+_n, |)$ and $(D^+_4100, |)$ are partial orders and the proof will be complete, right?